# ggvis - How to plot a barchart

Tags: r, layer, ggvis

I don't know what is wrong with my code. but i get this error:

```
> Visitas_Por_Fuente %>% ggvis(~Campanas1, ~sessions) %>% layer_bars()
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

I just want to create a bar graphic, that shows how many sessions by source do we have.

I use this code (but 'im not seeing the graph):

i've a data.frame that contains the following types of data:

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente %>% ggvis(~Campanas1, ~sessions) %>% layer_bars()
```

And this is the output for the str() function on my data.frame:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4177 obs. of  8 variables:
$ date         : Date, format: "2014-09-01" "2014-09-01" "2014-09-01" ...
$ dayOfWeekName: chr  "Monday" "Monday" "Monday" "Monday" ...
$ userType     : chr  "New Visitor" "New Visitor" "New Visitor" "New Visitor" ...
$ source       : chr  "(direct)" "amazon.es" "bing" "col128.mail.live.com" ...
$ Medium       : chr  "(none)" "referral" "organic" "referral" ...
$ campaign     : chr  "(not set)" "(not set)" "(not set)" "(not set)" ...
$ sessions     : num  97 1 2 1 5 2 124 1 35 1 ...
$ Campanas1    : Factor w/ 7 levels "Adwords","Campañas",..: 3 5 6 4 5 7 6 7 5 5 ...
```

head(Visitas_Por_Fuente)

Source: local data frame [6 x 8]

```
    date dayOfWeekName    userType                   source   Medium  campaign    sessions    Campanas1
1 2014-09-01        Monday New Visitor             (direct)   (none) (not set)       97      Directo
2 2014-09-01        Monday New Visitor            amazon.es referral (not set)        1  Referencias
3 2014-09-01        Monday New Visitor                 bing  organic (not set)        2          SEO
4 2014-09-01        Monday New Visitor col128.mail.live.com referral (not set)        1        Email
5 2014-09-01        Monday New Visitor         eloi.go.com referral (not set)         5  Referencias
6 2014-09-01        Monday New Visitor         facebook.com referral (not set)        2 Social Media
```

Answer (score 3):

i think the solution has to do with the term: "tidy data".

Steps:

1.- Simplify your data.frame with "select" from "Dplyr":

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente3 <- select(Visitas_Por_Fuente, Campanas1, sessions)
```

2.- Melt it with "melt" from "reshape2":

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente6 <- melt(Visitas_Por_Fuente3)
```

3.- Make the graph with ggvis:

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente6 %>% ggvis(~Campanas1, ~value) %>% layer_bars()
```

NOTE:

If you just try to make the graph without reshaping it, it won't work.

And i don't know WHY. They look to my the same, here you have the heads of the 2 data.frames:

A) Visitas_Por_Fuente3 - Without Reshaping it:

```
     Campanas1    sessions
1      Directo        97
2  Referencias        1
3          SEO        2
4        Email        1
5  Referencias        5
6 Social Media        2
```

B) Visitas_Por_Fuente6 - Reshaping it:

```
     Campanas1 variable value
1      Directo sessions    97
2  Referencias sessions     1
3          SEO sessions     2
4        Email sessions     1
5  Referencias sessions     5
6 Social Media sessions     2
```

Why is that? Any idea?

This is what i wanted, and got. How ever, is there a way to add the values for each column? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Same problem..solution works. Any insight on why the `melt` is necessary?

Comment: @JohnSG i did not have time to go deeper, but you should search for  "tidy data" hadley wickham to get mor information.